# Is there efficient way to deal with division by zero?

Tags: optimization, modeling, solver

I am trying to solve an optimization problem in which there is an objective function in the following form:
\begin{equation}f(x, y)=x+\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\end{equation}
Where, $x,y$ are positive variables with $LB=0$ and a finite $UB$.
When I run the model I have an issue that `division by zero`.
One possible way to do that is set a little number as a $LB$ but, I am not sure this would be a good idea.

**I was wondering if, is there any efficient way to solve this issue?**

Comment: What does $y$ represent?

Comment: You might be able to cast your problem as a conic optimization and then the problem goes away. See https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#a-resource-constrained-production-and-inventory-problem for an example.

Comment: @RobPratt, actually, this is a simple form of the objective function and what I'm looking for is dose any method exist to deal with that efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the problem is a minimization problem, you can use a [rotated second-order cone](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#rotated-quadratic-cones) (RSOC) formulation.
Specifically, write the objective as $x + 2t$, and add the constraint
$$
(t, y, 1) \in \mathcal{Q}^{1}_{r},
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
t \geq 0, y \geq 0, 2ty \geq 1,
$$
i.e., it yields $2t \geq \frac{1}{y}$.

RSOC constraints are supported by solvers such as CPLEX, Gurobi and Mosek.
If the rest of you problem is non-linear, I believe KNITRO supports combinations of conic and non-linear constraints.

If the objective $x + \frac{1}{y}$ is to be maximized, then the above formulation does not work.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. The objective function is minimization.

Answer (score 1):

Since $y$ is positive, your fraction is not only convex, but monotonically decreasing. This means that adding a $y \geq \epsilon$ constraint will not affect the (global) solution, and will also prevent the numerical issues of division by zero.

This means that you can add said constraint for each fractional variable in your objective, assuming it's positive, and and any NLP solver will solve it without issues.

A word of caution though if you also have constraints with this: since you are minimising, be mindful that this functional form is only convex for $\leq$ constraints. If it shows up in any other type of constraint, the procedure to handle it is different.

Comment: Because $y$ is positive, no disjunction is needed.

Comment: @Nikos Kazazakis, thanks for your answer but, I'm not sure I understand your first idea as well. Would you say please, how we can split the $y$ variable in the objective function?

Comment: @RobPratt Ah I missed that it's positive, thanks, I'll update.

Comment: @A.Omidi As Rob pointed out, $y$ is positive which means the procedure is much simpler, see updated answer :)

Comment: @Nikos Kazazakis, Many thanks for your detailed explanation.